# 1-Dimensional (1D) Plotting using SVM (e1071)

Tags: r, svm

I'm trying to do 1D SVM plotting using e1071 package in R.

I am new to this so I not sure whether the issue is that the e1071 package do not support 1D plotting (since I could not locate any 1D plotting information here: http://www.inside-r.org/node/57517, http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/e1071/docs/plot.svm) or there is something wrong with my formula here.

```
library(e1071)
data<-iris[,4:5]
#using subset of iris as data with Species as label
model<-svm(Species~.,data)

plot(model,data)
Error in plot.svm(model, data) : missing formula.

plot(model,data,Petal.Width~.)
Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : min not meaningful for factors
```

Thank you.

**Update**

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143173/5413930) which is saying that the 1D plotting is not supported in e1071. Since this answer is posted years ago, I wonder whether the 1D plotting is still not supported now.

Comment: It is a plotting problem, not a classification one.

Comment: What exactly do you expect the plot to look like in the 1-D case? What exactly is the output you are after here?

Comment: @MrFlick I expecting the plot to look something like this [plot](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-xLBj8-EvWdU/UNuDyX2K75I/AAAAAAAAAMY/Eg7Labb03zk/s1600/kernel_trick1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is really just about plotting, that's handled by `?plot.svm` if you pass an `svm` object as the first parameter. That function does not support 1D plots.

You can create your own with something like

```
plot(model.frame(model)[,2], col=predict(model))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and alternative!