# how to plot one-class SVM in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

i'm using the package e1071 in R in order to build a one-class SVM model. 
I was able to model it and print the model, but i am having difficulties plotting it.

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142294/how-do-i-plot-a-classification-graph-of-a-svm-in-r), and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375517/one-class-classification-with-svm-in-r?rq=1), which is using the iris dataset, but all SVM examples use C-classification.

```
library(e1071)

day = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
weather = c(6,5,4,3,2,1,0) #on the example, it was: c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
happy = factor(c(T,T,T,T,T,T,T)) #on the example it was: happy = factor(c(T,F,F,F,F,F,F))

d = data.frame(day=day, weather=weather, happy=happy)
model = svm(happy ~ day + weather, data = d, type='one-classification') #on the example it was: model = svm(happy ~ day + weather, data = d)

plot(model, d)
```

Since it is one-class i modified the factors to the same label. It gives the following error:

```
Error in rect(0, levels[-length(levels)], 1, levels[-1L], col = col)
  cannot mix zero-length and non-zero-length coordinates
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package 'e1071' was built under R version 3.2.3
2: In Ops.factor(yorig, ret$fitted) : '-' not meaningful for factors
```

I am using R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) (windows).

How can i plot this model?

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't one-classification require the `nu` parameter?

Comment: Hi @Sebastian M. Müller. Yes, it does, but if you do not put it takes the default value 0.5

Comment: have you tried just `plot(model)`?

Comment: Hi @lejlot i have. it gives an error of missing data... argument data missing...

Answer (score -1):

thanks. I guess [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017427/plotting-data-from-an-svm-fit-hyperplane)  works. If you are able to find how to plot for 2d in a quicker way, please share. Otherwise, this is great.

It presents a 3d plot for 3 feature values. It also draws the hyperplane and you can even play around with the nu value and see the increase or decrease of the margin. Very cool..